# can't check flutter doctor

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm installing Androit Studio in the second, but there were no such problems before. I am getting the following error in terminal -

```
    fatal: git repository (or one of parent directories) not found: .git
Building flutter tool...
/home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 24: cd: /home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (2 tries left)
/home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 24: cd: /home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (1 tries left)
Command 'pub upgrade' still failed after 10 tries, giving up.
```

Also, I tried to create a new flutter project in android studio, and tried to specify the path to the flutter sdk, but I get the message -

> Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location.

Although, I drive the path according to the results of the `flutter sdk-path` conmada
Please help solve this problem!

***PS: It's definitely not a network problem.***

***PSS: deleting the cache folder doesn't help***

***PSS: When I command git status, I get the error "On the stable branch
Your branch has been updated to reflect "origin/stable".
nothing to commit, no changes in working directory***

All activies -

```
daniil@daniil-laptop:~/flutter$ git status
On the stable branch
Your branch has been updated to reflect "origin/stable".

nothing to commit, no changes in working directory
daniil@daniil-laptop:~/flutter$ flutter doctor
fatal: git repository (or one of parent directories) not found: .git
Building flutter tool...
/home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 24: cd: /home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
/home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/internal/shared.sh: line 24: cd: /home/daniil/snap/flutter/common/flutter/packages/flutter_tools: No such file or directory
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (8 tries left)
```

I decided to remove the flutter that I installed via snap. And cloned the repository from git. But I realized that there are no cache folders.
When executing all the above commands - the errors do not change
[image: git clone]

Comment: Clearly Showing Network Issue

Comment: @TasnuvaTavasumoshin realy? but, i cann this question. Why?